# Can I replace Xbox 360 controller's battery?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I was playing Final Fantasy XIII-2 for hours and I saw that my controller had a single bar of battery life left. I told my neighbor my problem and he told me he had a Xbox 360 Rechargeable Battery Pack. I checked for the price of the latter and I can't afford them. Do I have to buy this pack for my controller or do I just have to buy new batteries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, you can find the battery slot on the back of the Xbox controller

[image: Xbox Controller]

It depends on the type of battery pack you do have. If you have a rechargeable battery pack (depending if you got it new or second hand) it should have come with a recharge cable. This is what it looks like:

[image: Rechargeable battery]

[image: Recharge Cable]

If you have a normal battery pack, all you need to do is replace the batteries. Two AA batteries will work, rechargeable or not will both work (I'd suggest rechargeable - bit more expensive, but you won't need to buy more!).

[image: AA Battery]

*Pictures not to scale.*

Comment: These pics are not AA sized....

Comment: Add a little Not to Scale somewhere

Comment: Thank you for the response. gonna buy me some batteries. I appreciate your very long but informative post sir

Comment: You can buy the batteries separate from the charger.  If you do want to buy the charging cable, it's sold as the [Play & Charge Kit](http://www.amazon.com/Xbox-360-Black-Play-Charge-Kit/dp/B000OYMYZQ).  It's sold in different colors, that link goes to the black version.

Comment: Forgot to mention, Microsoft also makes the [Quick Charge Kit](http://www.amazon.com/Xbox-360-Quick-Charge-Kit/dp/B009NAVOMG/ref=dp_ob_title_vg), which is an external recharger that can charge two Xbox 360 battery packs at once.  I don't think it ships with a battery pack, though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can replace the batteries. The wireless 360 controller uses two AA batteries, which are extremely common. Your parents might even keep some spares.

The battery holder is on the back of the controller; there's a little button there that releases it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to buy the rechargeable battery pack, but you need to invest in some new batteries.

You can, however, use normal rechargeable batteries without a problem. They might not last as long as their non-chargeable counterparts, but you'll be saving some money.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use two AA batteries, there is no need for a rechargable battery pack. I always use rechargeable batteries, but you can just use Alkaline, whatever floats your boat.